# Woocommerce - Can't display image within loop of cart items

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I have a loop of cart items in Woocommerce that currently only displays the name, quantity and price. I'm trying to also get the image thumbnail to display but it either gives me an error and the page doesn't load at all or it does load but it doesn't show anything.

```
<?php
                global $woocommerce;
                $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
                $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                if (!$items) {
                    echo '<span class="no-items-mini">No items added</span>';
                }
                    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
                        $_product = $values['data']->post; 
                        $link = get_permalink($_product);
                        echo "<span>";
                            echo $values['quantity']." x <a href='".$link."'>".$_product->post_title;
                        echo "<a/></span>";
                        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
                        echo "  Price: ".$currency.$price."<br>";
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $values['product_id'], 'single-post-thumbnail' );
                        echo "<img src=$image[0];/>";
                    }
                $total = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
                echo "<span class='mini-total'><b>Total: </b>".$currency.$total."</span>";
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have revisited your code, please try it:

```
<?php

    if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        echo '<span class="no-items-mini">No items added</span>';
    } else {
        $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
        $cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $_product = $cart_item['data'];
            $link = $_product->get_permalink();
            echo '<span>';
            echo $cart_item['quantity'].' x <a href="'.$link.'">'.$_product->get_title();
            echo '<a/></span>';
            $price = $_product->get_price();
            echo "  Price: " . $currency . $price . "<br>";
            echo $_product->get_image();
        }
    echo "<span class='mini-total'><b>Total: </b>". $currency . $cart_total ."</span>";
    }

?>
```

Its should work this time.